# Blazor onchange event with select dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

***Note**: this question was asked about a pre-release of Blazor (0.2.1).*

So I have been stuck trying to get a simple onchange to fire when a select dropdown value changes. Like so:

```
<select class="form-control d-flex" onchange="(dostuff())">
    @foreach (var template in templatestate.templates)
    {
        <option value=@template.Name>@template.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

with the method being called:

```
void dostuff()
{
   Console.WriteLine("first spot is firing");
    _template = templatestate.templates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == 
    _template.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("second spot is firing");
}
```

The result I get it no matter how I try to reorient it is this error in the browser.

```
Uncaught Error: System.ArgumentException: There is no event handler with ID 0
```

Is there something obvious and key that I am missing? Because I have a button `onclick` event that works just fine on the same page.

Comment: which version of blazor you are using, 0.1.0 or 0.2.0

Comment: I am using 0.2.1

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your answer should be in the cshtml:

```
<select @onchange="DoStuff">  //pre-3.0 versions: onchange=@DoStuff
    @foreach (var template in templates)
    {
        <option value=@template>@template</option>
    }
</select>
```

Then your @functions (in razor components @code instead.  See: [Razor Syntax: Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.2#functions)) should look like:

```
@functions {  //use @code in razor components.
    List<string> templates = new List<string>() { "Maui", "Hawaii", "Niihau", "Kauai", "Kahoolawe" };
    string SelectedString = "Maui";

    void DoStuff(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedString = e.Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + SelectedString);
    }
}
```

You could also just use a bind...

```
<select @bind="SelectedString"> //pre 3.0 bind="@SelectedString"
```

but @onchange="DoStuff" allows you to perform logic on selection.

Here's a link to some changes: [Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 5 release now available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-5-release-now-available/)

Comment: Blazor has changed dramatically from the first version... while I tested this and it worked well, the rapid changes to Blazor may well eventually cause this answer to no longer be applicable.  Please let me know if that happens and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Even with all the correct syntax, I'm not able to get this event to fire for the onchange event.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect the change.  I discovered that you can't name the .cshtml file select because it conflicts with the html element select.  Anyway, this works in a file called selector in the base get started package as of 09/19/2018.  Hopefully this helps ppl.  If it does, please upvote my answer, since it was downvoted.

Comment: Currently requires that you do <select @onchange=@DoStuff>  Note the @ in front of the on change

Comment: I just tried it again and yours still doesnt work mine works.  No idea why i am using the last version in Visual studio 19 preview.

Comment: @DaImTo Please specify the version of Blazor you are using as it may help others.

Comment: @Patrick Knott `@functions` has been removed in favor of `@code` at this point.

Comment: Actually onchange should be @onchange this syntax change in preview 6 - it's the final event-handler syntax for the 3.0 release.

Comment: Prefer answers by [@Rono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328871/6789816) or [@Pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839075/6789816) at this point.

Answer (score 42):

As an alternative to setting an onchange event, you could just bind the dropdown to a property and handle changes in the property set.  This way you get the value being selected all in the same process and without having to convert an object value.  Plus if you're already using @bind on the select, you are prevented from using onchange on it as well.

```
<select @bind="BoundID">
 ...
</select>

@code {
  private int? _boundID = null;
  private int? BoundID
  {
    get
    {
      return _boundID;
    }
    set
    {
      _boundID = value;
     //run your process here to handle dropdown changes
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for a select.

Comment: Very useful, especially if you need to change other dropdowns who have the same binding!

Comment: I love it. A more elegant way to handle this - this way you are binding the value, which you want to, and then saying oh by the way, when this value is set, do this for me, in a one-stop-shop that doesn't mess with UI code. Trying to bind and onchange at the same time at the UI level has an inherent problem. GOOD JOB

Answer (score 10):

Above answer didn't work for me, got compilation error.

below is my working code.

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@if (States != null)
{

<select id="SearchStateId" name="stateId" @onchange="DoStuff" class="form-control1">
    <option>@InitialText</option>
    @foreach (var state in States)
    {
        <option value="@state.Name">@state.Name</option>
    }
</select>
}


@code {
[Parameter] public string InitialText { get; set; } = "Select State";
private KeyValue[] States;
private string selectedString { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    States = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<KeyValue[]>("/sample-data/State.json");
}

private void DoStuff(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + selectedString);
}

public class KeyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Works for me in year 2021, with the @onchange="DoStuff"  (no brackets)

Comment: I'm glad for your contribution but "above answer" might change over time

Answer (score 3):

For starters you are not using the correct bind syntax:

`onchange="@dostuff"`

notice the @

Comment: Sure I tried 2 ways using the @. @dostuff() and @dostuff. Both give a compile error stating you cannot implicitly convert type void to object

Comment: Your code works for me. maybe you can share your whole project somewhere?

Comment: I apologize. I would like to share the code but at the moment it is completely broken so you wouldn't be able to debug and toggle that dropdown to see the exception. The latest blazor nuget packages broke the routing somehow so all you get is Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Router' cannot find any component with a route for '/'. even in the sample project

Comment: Share anyway, happy to help with that also

Comment: yes always use "@" and you also can use @onchange="dostuff"

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to the other answers that you can access the `select` value by using lambda expressions as well:

```
<select @onchange="@(e => ViewModel.TargetProperty = e.Value.ToString())">
```

In case you prefer to put your code right in the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
<select @onchange="(e => DoStuff(e.Value.ToString()))">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-2">
<label class="font-weight-bold f-14">Clase de vehículo</label>

<InputSelect class="form-control form-select" id="vehicleClass" ValueChanged="@((string value) => References(value))"
              Value="@dtoSearchVehicleBy.VehicleClass" ValueExpression="@(() => dtoSearchVehicleBy.VehicleClass)">
    <option selected>Seleccionar</option>
    @foreach (var vehicle in vehicleByClass)
    {
        <option value="@vehicle.VehicleClass"> @vehicle.VehicleClass</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
<div class="text-danger">
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => dtoSearchVehicleBy.VehicleClass)" />
</div>
```

```
        private void References(string value)
    {
        brand = dtoSearchVehicleBy.Brand;
        dtoSearchVehicleBy.VehicleClass = value;
        vehicleByBrandAndClass = vehicleByBrands.Where(x => x.Brand == brand && x.VehicleClass == value);
    }
```